# urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>

Tags: python, post

This is a simple php script located on my web server.

```
cat ../php/test.php
<?php
  echo "Hi";
?>
```

This is an embryo to a simple regression test of my web server in python. (I've only modified my user id in the URL.) It calls the script above.

```
!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                                                                   

def TC1():
    import json
    import urllib
    import urllib2

    url = 'http://ec2-user@ec2-00-00-00-00.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/test.php'
    post_params = {
        'foo' : 'bar'
        }

    params = urllib.urlencode(post_params)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url, params)
    json_response = json.loads(response.read())
    return

TC1()
```

When I run the script I get the following output. Why?

```
./suite.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./suite.py", line 18, in <module>
    TC1()
  File "./suite.py", line 14, in TC1
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url, params)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>
```

When I paste the URL in chrome I get the expected 'Hi' response, so the server side is ok.

Comment: User need a session ! How to manage sessions ? Can't jump middle point if using user actions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to fix python, urlopen error \[Errno 8\], using eventlet green](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32065895/how-to-fix-python-urlopen-error-errno-8-using-eventlet-green)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick. But I really don't know why. Great if someone can explain. I see examples like my first attempt all over.

```
params = urllib.urlencode(post_params)
f = urllib.urlopen(url, params)
print f.read()
```

Comment: Looks like the only subtantial difference on this code is that you are calling `urllib.urlopen` instead of `urllib2.urlopen`.